# Running middleware before URL Rewriting Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I have a really simple application that I'm using to test a combination of IIS-styled rewrite rules and simple user-maintained redirects. Where I'm struggling with why the `UseRewrite` option takes residence over my middleware.

The reason for using both is that the IIS rules are created fo chaining conditions to minimise the number of redirects. This is especially useful for me as I'm migrating content from multiple domains to a single domain an also dealing with a lot of historical redirects. This doesn't effect the question though.

The app I'm using to test this is really simple, and just gives the same response for every path:

```cs
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.Json;
using dotnet_test_urlrewrite;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiddleware<VanityRedirectMiddleware>();

var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions();
rewriteOptions.AddIISUrlRewrite(builder.Environment.ContentRootFileProvider, "url-rewrite.xml");
app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);

app.Use(async (HttpContext ctx, Func<Task> _) =>
{
  var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    {"Path", ctx.Request.Path},
    {"Date", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
    {"Method", ctx.Request.Method},
    {"QueryString", ctx.Request.QueryString.ToString()},
    {"Scheme", ctx.Request.Scheme},
    {"Host", ctx.Request.Host.ToString()}
  };
  
  ctx.Response.Headers.ToList().ForEach(header => data.Add($"Header: {header.Key}", header.Value));
  
  var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
  ctx.Response.Headers.ContentType = "application/json";
  await ctx.Response.WriteAsync(message);
});

app.Run();
```

As you can see, I'm picking up the URL rewrite file but before that, I'm registering my middleware. That middleware is - in this instance - super simple and the Invoke looks like this:

```cs
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("> Path: {0}", context.Request.Path);
        if (context.Request.Path.Equals("/vanity", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/vanity-target", false);
        }

        return _next(context);
    }
```

The problem I'm seeing is that *if* there is a rule in my redirects that also covers the `/vanity` path, this executes first and the vanity redirects never happen. SO or me, having this in an IIS rules map takes president:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Rule">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{StaticRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites" defaultValue="">
      <add key="/vanity" value="/stolen-vanity" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Is there something different about the way that the `UseRewriter()` method works that somehow always puts it at the front of the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your middleware you are always continuing to the next middlware. If you do a redirect you should end the response there by returning without calling `_next(context)`.

```cs
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("> Path: {0}", context.Request.Path);
        if (context.Request.Path.Equals("/vanity", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/vanity-target", false);
            return;
        }

        return _next(context);
    }
```

As it is now `Response.Redirect` will set the redirect headers but then call the next middleware which will overwrite whatever you set yourself.

Comment: oh wow. That's perfect, thank you. 
I can't believe I missed that. 

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer is that it is impossible to execute middleware in asp.net core before IIS Rewrite.**

According to the sample code you provided, I would like to briefly talk about the concept first. web.config works on the IIS web server, so the rules and rewriteMap in the configuration file are used at the server level.

Asp.net core application is hosted in the web server, `iis rewrite(**scope** :web server)` is not comparable to `UseRewriter(**scope**asp.net core application)`, because the scope of influence is different. Of course, both of these can meet the requirements of rewrite. iis rewrite is triggered when the request enters the IIS web server, and then enters the asp.net core application. If there are rewrite-related configurations in the middleware in your asp.net core application, it can also will be executed.

**Suggestion**

As we all know, asp.net core application can be cross-platform, so if we have a need for rewrite, we can implement it in the middleware instead of configuring it in web.config.

In this way, a lot of trouble can be saved for future deployment, and it may also be easily migrated to a linux server.

Comment: This isn't using web.config as far as I know; `UseRewriter()` is an extension to IApplicatonBuilder that registers its own middleware (at least that's what I'd understood). In IIS in this application, the URL Rewrite module has no idea what is going on and has no rewrite rules listed.

In the target project (this being the simplified view), I have team members running this application on macOS, Linux and Windows, and all of the current rewrite rules are fine. The only thing I have in web.config is to tell IIS to run the aspnet core application, but it has no reference to these rewrite rules.

Comment: I would add, I'm verging on creating a more complete middleware to replace `UseRewriter`, but want to avoid that if possible, as the existing rewrite rules are - in my opinion - easier to maintain in the XML file.

Comment: @mnield is right here. The call to `AddIISUrlRewrite()` is just a convenience-method to load an XML-file in the same format that the IIS UrlRewriter uses for the UrlRewrite middleware, it doesn't configure IIS to perform the rewriting in any way.

Comment: the title makes me misunderstand